# jQuery resize ( drag n drop ) & crop

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, resize, crop

I've been working on a project for a while which involves the following ( this is the bit where I'm stuck ):
I have to upload an image,with a non-flash uploader only ie: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload.
After this image is uploaded it should open in a lightbox ( fancybox, etc ) and the user should have the option to
a) resize the image using drag n drop function ( not to give the actual coordinates );
b) crop the resized image to a fixed width & height. 
It would be great if the above can be done simultaneously!

I've been looking for plugins and plugins, but I can't find anything which does the above together.
Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks,
Seb

Comment: I just utterly like this composite: drag n drop n crop

Answer (score 2):

For the client side, I recommend checking out the [imgAreaSelect plugin](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) - it's provides the functionality you mention and is very customizable.

In terms of actually creating a modified image/thumbnail, usually you'll post the coordinates to your backend and do the actual cropping/resizing/saving there, for instance with Python's PIL or some other imaging library depeding on your language.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the two options I mentioned above have to be on the customers website. 
[Here's an image](http://i.imgur.com/WdHnC.jpg) of what I need exactly:  
  
- with the arrows I'm re-sizing the image ( I might need the aspect ratio to remain intact )  
  
- the square with the squares ( logic! ) on the top left & right and bottom left & right symbolizes the actual cropping.

Comment: well, the part of having the user do some resizing or cropping is relatively easy, e.g. see jquery ui: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-aspectRatio - however, at the end of the day, actual image manipulation will have to take place on a server... also i can't see the 'image of what I need' you  mentioned in your comment